# different results from Array.join()

Tags: javascript, join, push

Look at the following code:

```
var words = [];        
var temp_words =[];
var div = document.getElementById('div');
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt  = evt.keyCode;
    var event = String.fromCharCode(evt);
    // alert(event);
    temp_words.push(event);
    var w = temp_words.join("");
    words.push(w);
}
```

HTML

Now in google console I see the results.

If I type in the textarea sanmevg saini then the `words` array returns:

```
["s", "sa", "san", "sanm", "sanme", "sanmev", "sanmevg", "sanmevg ", "sanmevg s", "sanmevg sa", "sanmevg sai", "sanmevg sain", "sanmevg saini"]
```

not `["sanmevg saini"]`

and if I write `[''a,'b','c', ' ','d' ].join('')` then it returns the expected results i.e.
`['abc d']`. So what's the problem in my code?

Comment: Check the content of temp_words

Comment: the content in `temp_words` is `["s", "a", "n", "m", "v", "e", "g", " ", "s", "a", "i", "n", "i"]`

Comment: Instead of `words.push(w)`, try `words = w.split(' ')`;

Comment: How about the content of 'w'?

Comment: thanks you Mr. Diaz and sir cory for you kind attention on my question.

Comment: What is a "google console"???

Comment: there is a option or place in developer tool where you can test your javascript codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not necessary to use the var temp_word, the var word is enough. the word array store the merge value of the temp_word every time you press a key so you get your wrong value. the code should be this:

```
<textarea id="div"></textarea>
<script>
    var words = [];        
    var temp_words =[];
    var div = document.getElementById('div');
    document.onkeypress = function(evt){
        evt  = evt.keyCode;
        var event = String.fromCharCode(evt);
        words.push(event);
        div.innerHTML = words.join("")
    }
</script>
```

I wrote a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/bS4WP/
by the way,  your code is ugly and indentation is wrong, your code should be as beautiful as your girlfriend.

Answer (score 0):

Every time a key is pressed the another word is added to the `words` array. Just use `words = temp_words.join("")`;

Comment: Then just `words = [temp_words.join("")]`. It's just that I don't see the point of an array with one value.

Comment: @openorclose: Yeah, that's true. In that case there's really no point in having any arrays at all. Just a `words` variable that has characters appended to it. However, it just seems like the event should copy the value straight out of the textbox to its destination, unless some kind of history is needed.